# CSS Laravel Bootstrap 4

Tags: css, laravel, bootstrap, css3

Tengo problemas con esta nueva versión y tengo algunas cosas que si me las esta recogiendo el `Bootstrap4`y otras no.

Por ejemplo no es capaz de enseñar estos iconos:

```
<a href="#" class="btn btn-danger"> <i class="fa fa-cog"          aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
<a href="#" class="btn btn-warning"><i class="fa fa-window-close" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
```

Ni este otro

```
    <section class="section-admin">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <h3 class="panel-tittle">@yield('title')</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body">
            @include('flash::message')
            @yield('content')
        </div>
    </div>
</section>

<footer class="admin-footer">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
        <div class="containter-fluid">
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
                <p class="navbar-text"> Todos los derechos reservados &copy {{ date('Y') }} </p>
                <p class="navbar-text navbar-right"><b>Deimos Castilla-La Mancha</b></p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
</footer>
```

sin embargo botones como

```
<div class="form-group">
    {!! Form::submit('Registrar', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary']) !!}
</div>
```

Funcionan perfectamente.

Comment: Bootstrap 4 no incluye por defecto ningún pack de iconos. Esas clases que usas para los iconos son de [Font Awesome](http://fontawesome.io/icons/) ¿Has incluido esos iconos en tu proyecto?

Comment: Ups, pensaba que venian, no lo hcie no.
Y los divisores? eso si deberia de funcionar no?

Comment: ¿Qué son los divisores?

Comment: Los `div`que muestro tambien con sus clases, no funcionan

Comment: en Bootstrap 4 ya no existen los panels, ahora se usa la clase card: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/card/

Comment: Asegúrate de que las clases son las correctas, bootstrap 4 no es retrocompatible con bootstrap 3, lo mismo que éste no lo era con la versión 2. Piensa además que sigue estando en versión beta, seguramente tenga pequeños fallos por arreglar. Quizá deberías plantearte usar la versión 3.3.7, que la más reciente estable

Comment: Vale vale, mucho cambio y no lo sabia, por cierto entonces para utilizar los glyphicon de v3 en v4 como seria?

Comment: @AlbertoCeperodeAndrés https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/migration/#components

Comment: podrías usar este CDN: //netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap-glyphicons.css

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Estás usando las clases definidas para Bootstrap v3.3, pero Bootstrap v4 es una re-escritura de toda la librería, sin pensar en retrocompatibilidad:

- No hay soporte para navegadores antiguos (IE9 y anteriores)
- Las clases `col-N-xs` se ha renombrado a `col-N`
- Se usa flex-box por defecto
- Muchos componentes han sido reescritos o sustituidos: panel, well, thumbnail desaparecen en favor de card.
- Glyphicons son ahora externos, permitiendo usar distintos paquetes
- [Y muchos otros cambios](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/migration/)